# OnTouch in MapView only fires the first time

Tags: android, event-handling, android-mapview, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to implement a double-tap zoom like function in my MapView. The event always fires the first time, but never subsequent times. Below is my code. I have a feeling it has something to do with the map controller getting lost after the first time the event is fired.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class mainmap extends MapActivity implements OnTouchListener{

    long lasttime = -1;
    MapController mapc;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapc = mapView.getController();
        mapView.setOnTouchListener(this);       
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            if(event.getEventTime()-lasttime<2000){
                mapc.zoomInFixing((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());             
            }
        }       
        lasttime=event.getEventTime();
        return true;
    }

  }
```

I have also tried editing the OnTouch method to cast the incoming View to a MapView, getting the controller while the event is fired. However, I get the same results where the first event is fired but not subsequent ones.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            if(event.getEventTime()-lasttime<2000){
                ((MapView)v).getController().zoomInFixing((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());                
            }
        }       
        lasttime=event.getEventTime();
        return true;
    }
```

Being as basic as possible, I cut out all of the code in the OnTouch method and programmed it to simply display a small toast message.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

               Toast.makeText(this,"Down!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }       

        return true;
}
```

This works as expected, displaying the Toast each time the MapView is touched.

I don't understand why the event will fire properly in this case but not in my previous implementation.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using this method `"mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);"` then your `touch` is working at once .

Please remove that that line and check I am sure it will work..

In some case if you want BuiltInZoomControls then you can you OnTouch method of Overlay like as below..

```
public class MapOverlay extends Overlay {

    public MapOverlay(Context ctx) {super(ctx);}

    @Override
    protected void draw(Canvas c, MapView osmv, boolean shadow) { }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {
        //Write yout touch code here..
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is true, but why touch event called once?

Comment: I didn't waste my time on it, so I don't know about it. I think no need builtInZoom Button bcz map already support multi-touch zoom & you can also add your custom button for zoom In/Out..

Comment: How in the Overlay class related with this problem - the mapView and the zoom controls?

Comment: To add a bit more to CapDroid's answer, I created an instance of MapOverly as shown above, and added it to the overlays of the map. And it works as advertised. :)

Answer (score 2):

Subclass MapView and override dispatchTouchEvent like below and use the subclass instead.

```
public class MyMap extends MapView{
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
         if (mOnMovedListener!= null) {
                mOnMovedListener.onMove(ev);
            }
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    private OnMovedListener mOnMovedListener;

    public void setOnMovedListener(OnMovedListener mOnMovedListener) {
        this.mOnMovedListener= mOnMovedListener;
    }
}
```

register for listener like any other!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem - I couldn't drag and scroll the map because it was receiving only `ACTION_DOWN` events. It can be solved by adding `android:clickable="true"` to the `MapView` or by calling `mapView.setClickable(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [`GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html) instead of `OnTouchListener`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to implement an OnDoubleTapListener to handle this functionality instead. 

I'm still confused though. 

I understand OnDoubleTapListener is probably the best way to handle this, but the code I posted in theory should work, right?

Answer (score 0):

you should at least put

```
lasttime=event.getEventTime();
```

under the

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) brakes
```

while `onTouch` detect `ACTION_UP` event of your click. So any time you make a click it is called 2 times

Answer (score -1):

Implement the Touch event on the map view instead. That will work!!

```
    // The onTouch event of the Map itself does not fire!
    // We must implement it on the mapView!!!
    mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            // Your code and remember to return true!                

            return (true);
        }
    });
```